# How to iterate over an spreadsheet with openpyxl and find what an user have assigned to them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, openpyxl

I have a spreadsheet, in which Users names are in one column and their equipment is in another ("B" & "E").
This is an made up example from the sheet:

```
A          B           C           E         F
CI Number  Username   Department   Equipment  Model
  1423    Mike Brandt   Sales        iPhone    8
  5345    Mike Brandt   Sales        iPad      Air
  8473    Christina      HR          iPhone    6s
  8474    Christina      HR          Laptop   T500
  0983    Christina      HR          iPhone    8
```

My thought was to iterate over each row in B and if it is the same User, then check if they have the same equipment.

```
Mike Brandt --> iPhone
Mike Brandt --> iPad
```

this would would be false, as Mike have an iPhone and iPad
However with Christina

```
Christina --> iPhone
Christina --> Laptop
Christina --> iPhone
```

Would be true, and an "*" is put in cell G to mark an user have duplicated items.

This is for my job, where we sometimes have to manually read an excel sheet and look if an user did not return their device before receiving a new one. (There might be up to a 1000 users, so this is why I am attempting it)
I cannot figure out what I have to do in order to compare the user and see if they have two of the same devices.

```
import openpyxl

path = '/home/steven/Documents/Python/Arbejde/test.xlsx'

# Open Workbook & Worksheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()

def clean_list(ws):
    #Loop over e rows, and check each cell for a match.
    for row in range(2, ws.max_row+1):
        for column in "BE":
            cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
            if ws[cell_name].value == ws[cell_name].value:
                #Check code should be here

print(clean_list(ws))
```

I expected the out put to be something like this:

```
8473    Christina      HR          iPhone    6s *
8474    Christina      HR          Laptop   T500
0983    Christina      HR          iPhone    8
```

**Solution**:

```
import pandas as pd

path = '/home/steven/Documents/Python/Arbejde/Altudstyr.xlsx'
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Ark1') # Reads the excel_sheet

#If dup, print a "*" to column Duplet.
df['Duplet'] = df.duplicated(['End user', 'Standard']).map({True: '*', False: ''})

df.to_excel('Sorted_List.xlsx')
```

Comment: You should really use a database for this kind of task, though Pandas will let you work with worksheets as if they are single database tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you could use the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['Username', 'Equipment'])
users = df.loc[mask, 'Username']
result = df[df['Username'].isin(users)]

print(result)
```

which gives as print output:

```
   CI Number   Username Department Equipment Model
2       8473  Christina         HR    iPhone    6s
3       8474  Christina         HR    Laptop  T500
4        983  Christina         HR    iPhone     8
```

Comment: Thanks, using panda seems like a much better option. However is it possible to make df['Duplet'] = df.duplicated(['End user', 'Standard']) print an "*" instead off 0 and 1's? I've trying storing the value of df.duplicate but as it is a series, it is ambiguous and I do not see a way to access the second value "E" column.

Comment: Try `df.duplicated(['End user', 'Standard']).map({True: '', False: '*'})`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do a mapping like for a user a set with the device that would remove duplicates. Later you can use the set to write separate rows.

Comment: A mapping like a dictionary which value = user key = device? and then later I can compare the individual dictionary with the excel sheet to see for duplicates?